# Update a custom variable and access it from another Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins job that is called apps-web-server and this job needs to access a value from another job. On the other job, I need to write this value somewhere preferably a Jenkins variable. However, I'm not sure how I can make that accessible from another job. The value is just a dynamic folder name that gets set when job runs successfully.

I want to access it this way via https. It's really simple.

https://ci.jenkins.io/job/Reporting/job/backend-plugin-report-card/lastStableBuild/buildNumber

I would like to access it this way

https://ourinternalserver/job/the-other-jenkins-job/lastStableBuild/folderName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest way would be to write the variable into a [properties file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties) and the archive this file as an artifact in post build action. Then you can use the artifact URL or [Copy Artifact plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to access it.

In the other job you can evaluate the contents using [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin). Or in the simplest case you can get away by sourcing the file in your build step.

Comment: Ok, I'll try your solution. I'll do some reading since I'm new to Jenkins. So looks like I may need to request to have that plugin installed.

Comment: You might be able get away with it without any plugins. See my edits. But it really depends how you intent to use the variable in the other job.

Comment: What do you mean by "sourcing the file in your build step"? How is this done? What would be the filename?

Comment: as long as i can save the value to anywhere(not via git) and access it from another job, i'll be very happy

Comment: Looks like I really don't need java to write to a properties file. I can use nodejs or even bash as long as I'm able to create this properties file.

Comment: Yes, you can use any tool you like to write and read the properties file. Or you can even use json file or plain text if you prefer. I just mentioned properties file, because EnvInject plugin supports that format.

Comment: Finally, we devs had agreement today. I told them that the easiest way is to use triggers in downstreamParameterized. I got it to worked. And yes, I also used EnvInject. On my shell I had to echo the value to env.properties file.